# Mocha does not see bundled js

Tags: javascript, typescript, mocha.js

I just started with js tests. Generally, my js experience is very limited. I was tasked with creating tests, but I hit a wall and I do not know how to proceed further.

The project I work on is in TypeScript. I use gulp + browserify to bundle compiled ts scripts into a single js file. But I cannot access any of the functions inside bundled js file from test file. I created a very basic test project, to try to understand what is what. I basically have 2 ts files:

separated.ts

```
export class separated {
  static getDataFromSeparated(value: number): boolean {
    if (value > 1) {
      return true;
    }
  }
}
```

and app.ts

```
import { separated } from './separated';
export { separated }

function getData(value) {
  if (value > 1) {
    return true;
  }
}

module.exports = getData;

export function getAnotherData(value) {
  return separated.getDataFromSeparated(value);  
}
```

I have 2 gulp tasks:

1. Compiles ts into separate js files.
2. Compiles ts and bundles into a sigle file. (my desired outcome)

The tests for 1. are running fine:

```js
const getData = require('./dist/app');
const getAnotherData = require('./dist/app');
const separated = require('./dist/separated').separated;

var assert = require('assert');

describe('Test Suite 11 - functions', function () {
  it('getData - from module', function () {
    assert.ok(true, getData(2));
  })

  it('getAnotherData - from export', function () {
    assert.ok(true, getAnotherData(2));
  })

  it('separated.getData', function () {
    assert.ok(true, separated.getDataFromSeparated(2));
  })
})
```

The tests for bundled do not work:

```js
const getData = require('./dist/appBundled');
const getAnotherData = require('./dist/appBundled');
const separated = require('./dist/appBundled').separated;

var assert = require('assert');

describe('Test Suite 21 - functions', function () {
  it('getData - from module', function () {
    assert.ok(true, getData(2));
  })

  it('getAnotherData - from export', function () {
    assert.ok(true, getAnotherData(2));
  })

  it('separated.getData', function () {
    assert.ok(true, separated.getDataFromSeparated(2));
  })
})
```

I get for example: `getData is not a function` (all tests fail with the same reason `... is not a function`. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i donot have enough reputation to add a comment. so have you tried checking throught the files itself. the uncompiled version of your project. because, as far my knowledge goes tests cannot parse the compiled version and thus it fails

Comment: Pity. I was hoping to used Visual Studio test reader to handle my tests. It handles js without any issue, but it cannot see TS. Anyway, thanks for your suggestion, it helped me!